# Yahoo currency api

Tags: currency

I've had a currency widget made for me which is based on http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select

I am wondering if I can use it on my site, which even though it not more than a hobby could be considered commercial inasmuch as it has affliate adverts.

How could I ask Yahoo to confirm if I can use it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is off topic**, considered this is a quant board.

However, if you earn money (even just a little) on the site, I'm pretty sure it will be considered a commercial site.

Yahoo! encourage you to register your site, if they approve the site, then you are good to go.

Taken from ["Yahoo! Developer Network Guidelines"](http://info.yahoo.com/guidelines/us/yahoo/ydn/ydn-3955.html):

> Please see our FAQ for more information about these non-commercial use only services. If you use these services in your application, we encourage you to register your application to confirm that your usage is acceptable. We typically do not grant additional queries for these non-commercial use only services.

Direct link to the [FAQ](https://developer.yahoo.com/faq/).